# How can I dynamically name an object using a string?

Tags: java

I am a Java beginner, and was wondering how you can name an instance of a class using a string, and then in turn create  a `case:` using that string/object, while keeping this completely automated (using `System.in.read()`, for instance)?

Comment: Be more specific .. the question is not clear enough (atleast to me :( )

Comment: Dynamically naming variables is difficult partially because it's usually a terrible idea. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: it's probably better to store name/value pairs in a Map...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variable *names* are merely a convenience for the programmer - they are not even kept track of after your code is compiled. Consequently, it is not possible to name variables dynamically like that. You could try using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to mimic this, however:

```
Map<String, MyClass> map = new HashMap<String, MyClass>();
map.put("xyz", new MyClass());  // or something like that

...
```

Now you can reference the object associated with the string `"xyz"` via `map.get("xyz")`.

Comment: Sorry, This Was A Stupid Question, In Which i Now Have The Answer To, Srry For The Inconvenience!

Comment: @user2565202 The only stupid question is an unasked one :-) Anyway, don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

While this is a very bad idea(use some sort of hashmap instead) it is possible using the paint known as [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). I personally do ***not*** recommend this.

Let's say your class is called `Foo` and contains fields `bar` and `baz`.

Now, lets say that we're inside class `Foo` so we can use the `this` keyword. If working with an existing reference to the object in question, change `this` to it. `fName` is the name of the variable we want.

```
Class<?> c = this.getClass();
Field ourField = c.getDeclaredField("fName");
Object ourValue = ourField.get(this);
```

Do note that this is painful, slow, and requires extra work to access primitives.

If `ourField` is an `int`, for instance, we'll want to change the last value to:

```
int intVal=ourField.getInt(this);
```